# iReport Spring loaded Hibernate connection

Tags: hibernate, spring, jasper-reports, ireport

i'm experiencing difficulties while trying to create a report using iReport via a Spring loaded Hibernate connection because i'm using spring. the problem is when i try to create a database connection i chose Spring loaded Hibernate connection ireport asks me to give the name of Spring configuration file and the session factory bean id, for Spring configuration: application-context.xml, session factory bean id: sessionFactory.
but when i test the connection ireport diplays this error message:

> nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:class
>   path resource[application-context]
>   cannot be opened because it does not
>   exist

best regards.

Comment: Show the code and any pertinent settings.

Comment: @ Dave Jarvis for the settings i added the application-context's path to the iReport's class path also added hibernate configurations's class path and maping files (.java) to the class path.

Comment: also added the jar needed for oracle database connection

Comment: That isn't showing the code, cascadox: That is describing what you've done. Without actually seeing what you've done, we have no way of knowing what has gone wrong. How have you set the CLASSPATH, for example? How is the report being executed? Are you calling the JasperReports API directly; if so, how?

Comment: @  Dave Jarvis maybe i didn't well explained my problem... i set the classpath on iReport so like that iReport can find the hibernate configuration file and the jars needed to have access  to database,i didn't created the report yet and i didn't tryed to call it yet, iReport is a software that helps in designing the reports, to do that i have to connect it to the database and since i'm using Spring i should use Spring loaded Hibernate connection. but iReport asks me to give the Spring configuration file name and the session factory bean id, when i do so it gives me the error shown before.

Comment: Explaining the problem isn't an issue. I understand you are using Spring and Hibernate. Show the code. Show the settings. Use screen captures. Use http://pastebin.com/. The computer is returning a `FileNotFoundException` this is likely because the `CLASSPATH` is not set correctly, or you are missing JAR files. There is no way of knowing how to help you because we do not know the `CLASSPATH` value. We need to see the technical details, not explanations.

Comment: @Dave Jarvis ok  here is my hibernate configuration file:
http://pastebin.com/VNr7zQpj
 and here is my application-context :
http://pastebin.com/jadcvTUi
and here is the paths i added:

Hibernate configuration file location: C:\Users\Omar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Gpsi\src\main\resources 

Jar path : C:\Users\Omar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Gpsi\lib\unknown\binary\ojdbc14\SNAPSHOT\ojdbc14-SNAPSHOT.jar
 
Maped java classes: C:\Users\Omar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Gpsi\src\main\java\com\mycompany\model

Comment: @cascadox Hi, just a friendly reminder that the first configuration file you posted there contains a username and password. I *assume* they are dummy-values, but I could be wrong :)

Comment: @ Lasse V. Karlsen thanks lot for your concern but they are not the correct values so no worries

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to Tools/Options/ClassPath, and add the folder that contains your configuration file.

Then in the dataset configuration, enter in just the filename for the spring configuration.  You must enter the entire filename, so it would be "application-context.xml".

You seem to have left off the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these steps

1: First go to Tools->Options->iReport->Classpath location

In this tab you need to add Folder location which contains your applicationContext.xml.

2: Add the Same version of Spring and Hibernate Jar files also.And don't add unwanted jar files because it will create some other problems.

3: Now Open Datasources dialog and Click New –> Spring loaded Hibernate Connection.

```
4:Configure Connection name,Spring Configuration should be
```

applicationContext.xml and your session factory Bean ID.

Still have any doubt Check the Screenshot in below url

http://www.techpages.org/ireport/spring-loaded-hibernate-connection/2460/